# Problem after upgrade to GNOME Shell 3.4 (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: 11.10, gnome, command-line

I updated the GNOME Shell by [these points](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/new-gnome-3-4-release-offers-features-fun-ui-finesse/):

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
- sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Unfortunately, no longer work themes and extensions.

[image]

How can I fix it (or return to the previous version)?

Regards and I hope to help.

**Edit:**

I noticed that I can not update **gnome-shell-extension-common**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the extension may only require slight modification to the metadata.json file to be available to gnome 3.4 users.  For instance I downloaded the EvilStatusIconForever extension for 3.2 and added 3.4 to the metadata.json and it works just fine.  Others, such as theming support require more.  Theming support as listed on gnome extensions web site breaks the Gnome Advanced Settings program, but someone lists a hack in the comments involving moving an xml file (see the website for details).  This hack allows you to continue to theme in 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

The gnome shell extensions are out of date, meaning that they support either Gnome 3.2 or Gnome 3.3. Its better to go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ and check which extensions are  compatible with Gnome 3.4. You can also install them directly from the browser if required! 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I haven't tried the update myself, however, I do know there is only about 10 extensions that still work with gnome 3.4 so there is going to be some compatibility issues, plus as stated in my article on 11.10 beware of the risks.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Shell 3.4 is designed for Ubuntu 12.04+, if you not remove Unity when you login use this and remove gnome-shell. Delete after ppa:// and install ppa from stable Gnome-Shell.

Comment: Currently, because of problems with GNOME Shell, try Unity.
If I upgrade Ubuntu, GNOME Shell will operate? Do I have to install them?