# GNOME Shell 3.4 - I can't change theme

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes

[Problem after upgrade to GNOME Shell 3.4 (Ubuntu 11.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116795/problem-after-upgrade-to-gnome-shell-3-4-ubuntu-11-10/)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 over the previous setting the /home partition.

I installed the GNOME Shell, unfortunately I can not change a theme: http://ubuntu.pl/forum/download/file.php?id=2631

Answer (score 4):

Here is the right way to get gnome-tweak-tool (advanced settings) to work therefore shell themes and extensions to work **WITHOUT** breaking your gnome shell

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
(type N and press enter at the end of the process)
```

Restart the shell (Alt F2 >> r >> enter)

Comment: doesn't this only give you beta builds of gnome shell and its components?

Comment: This worked on 12.04 and gnome 3.4, thanks a lot ! Could you explain a bit more what it does, to be precise (pun freakin' intended) ?

Comment: not every component of GNOME Shell is installed here. The latest gnome-session of GNOME Shell (3.4) is currently conflicted with that of Ubuntu 12.04 (3.2) and updating from 3.2 to 3.4 will also mean automatically delete all packages of Ubuntu 12.04 (sounds stupid right). Therefore, if we don't purge the PPA right away after installing the two needed components, we will probably break not only GNOME Shell but also the whole Ubuntu when updating the system in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I used Synaptic to have more control over the process.

1) Enable the Gnome 3 ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

2) Use Synaptic to install updates from gnome3-team/gnome3

3) Enable the Gnome Shell Testing ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
```

4) Use Synaptic to install gnome-tweak-tool and gnome-shell-extensions from ricotz/testing

3) Disable the Gnome Shell Testing ppa either in Synaptic or from a terminal

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing
```

Now I can apply themes to my Gnome Shell which adds a very nice touch. I did find however that the extensions web page https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ where you manage your installed extensions no longer works. I suspect that installing the gnome-shell package from Gnome Shell Testing will install a compatible version of the browser plugin but that is risky and maybe not important as long as the gnome-tweak-tool is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 12.04 gnome shell got an upgrade to 3.4 , this said none of your old extensions will work. you will need the `user-theme` extension which can easily be acquired from  [the gnome shell extensions site](http://extensions.gnome.org)

After installing the extension , you will need to enable it , i use `gnome-tweak-tool` for this , enable it by going to "shell extensions" in the left hand pane , then under "themes > shell theme" is where you can change your themes

Comment: What do you actually *do* with the `user-theme` extension one it's installed? I have themes installed, but there's nowhere to change the GNOME Shell theme.